# Loop in thread stopping when using Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

My code is below. It is meant to pop a tkinter window when the user clicks CTRL + X and close that window when CTRL + A is pressed. The problem is that when the window is closed after is opened the while loop in `lookForKeys` stops.

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
import keyboard as k

running = False


def main():
    global root
    print('Opening...')
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("340x740+1550+50")
    root.title('Custom Mic')
    root.resizable(0,0)    
    root.attributes('-topmost', True)
    root.update()

    root.mainloop()

def closeOverlay():
    print('Closing...')
    root.destroy()
    root.quit()


def openOverlay():
    global overlayThread
    print('Opening...')
    overlayThread = Thread(target = main)
    overlayThread.start()

def lookForKeys():
    global running

    while True:
        print(running)
        if k.is_pressed("ctrl+x") and running == False:
            running = True
            openOverlay()

        if k.is_pressed("ctrl+a") and running == True:
            running = False
            closeOverlay()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainThread = Thread(target = lookForKeys)
    mainThread.start()
```

Any helped is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the function `closeOverlay` in a thread and it worked.

```
        if k.is_pressed("ctrl+a") and running == True:
            running = False
            closeOverlayThread = Thread(target=closeOverlay)
            closeOverlayThread.start()
```